# How to calculate cart item's discount based on discount type [ Buy1 Get 1 offer ]

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, laravel-blade

I have a table in my DB.

Carts Table:

```
id| user_id | product_id | title |price |tax| quantity | discount | discount_type
1 | 1       | 2          | Watch |  50  | 5 |   2      |   Null   | buy1get1
2 | 1       | 4          | S-Pen |  30  | 5 |   1      |     5    | amount
3 | 1       | 3          | Cover |  25  | 5 |   1      |     5    | percent
```

My page loops through cart items in my database and displays them on the page.

I have 4 types of discounts [**discount_type**]:

```
Amount  |  Percent  |  Buy1 Get1  |  Buy2 Get1
```

**What I need:**

I don't know how to calculate the discount [throught the whole cart items, not each item] if the discount type are [ 'Buy1 Get1' OR 'Buy2 Get1' ]

**Part of CartController Discount Code for (amount, percent discounts ):**

```
if ($discount_applicable) {
if ($product->discount_type == 'percent')
{
  $price -= ($price*$product->discount)/100;
}
elseif ($product->discount_type == 'amount')
{
   $price -= $product->discount ;
}
elseif($product->discount_type == "buy1get1")
{
    $product->discount = 0;
    if ($request['quantity'] >= $product->min_qty && $request['quantity'] >= 2) {
    $total_price_after_discount = ( ($price + $tax) *$request['quantity'] ) - ( floor($request['quantity']/2) * $price );
                }
}
elseif ($product->discount_type == 'buy2get1') {
    $product->discount = 0;
    if ($request['quantity'] >= $product->min_qty && $request['quantity'] >= 2) {
    $total_price_after_discount = ( ($price + $tax) *$request['quantity'] ) - ( floor($request['quantity']/3) * $price );
        }
        }
}
```

The code above successfully calculates the discounts for each item (row in DB ), but I need to deal with it on the Cart level ( all items in the Cart).

How can I implement the [ 'Buy1 Get1' OR 'Buy2 Get1'] offers for all cart Items?

if the discount_type is [ Buy1get1] I need to make the cheapest item included in the offer, How to do this with the given cart table?

Any ideas or concepts would be truly appreciated.

P.s: I'm using Laravel based CMS [ Active eCommerce CMS ]

Answer (score 0):

You have to introduce coupons for your offers & discounts. Which will simplify your concept & pattern.

You can have better idea from below.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306959/implementing-buy-one-get-one-for-free-coupon-logic-for-shopping-cart

Comment: Thank you for replying, but it's not that simple. What if the cart has ( 3 items of buy1get1 and 2 of 'amount' and 1 item with no discount)? I mentioned that I don't want to calculate individual cart item discounts, I already managed to do it for each item. I need to calculate the discount based on all cart items together if I make myself clear. please let me know if you have any ideas, Thanks

Comment: I have edit the answer